# WildFly - is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.__TimerPool]

Tags: jdbc, jboss, datasource, wildfly, connection-pooling

I have followed this manual to migrate from GlassFish to WildFly:
http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/

However I'm getting the following error when running my application in WildFly:

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "exampleProject-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"exampleProject-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/exampleProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#exampleProjectPU\".**FIRST_PHASE** **is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.__TimerPool]**",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"exampleProject-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/exampleProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#exampleProjectPU\" **is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.__TimerPool]**"
]}

The error talks about jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.__TimerPool. Any idea of what should I do? I'm using WildFly 10 and MySQL as database.

Comment: The error states that your persistence unit *exampleProjectPU* is missing. How are you packing your *persistence.xml* file in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about this. __TimerPool was the name of a Datasource in GlassFish and I was using it without knowing it, I simply removed the persistence.xml file that contained it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your standalone.xml. It must be having a datasource with pool-name "exampleProjectPU" . Something like this. Please remove the full xml block.

```
<datasources>
       <datasource jndi-name="xxx:exampleProjectPU" pool-name="exampleProjectPU" enabled="true">

<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/SID</connection-url>
             <driver>oracle</driver>
                  <security>
                        <user-name></user-name>
                        <password></password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

- Go to deployments folder and check if there is any sample project with name "example project.war". If yes, remove it and start the server again. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to change your mysql-connecter to bin file like mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin
2. make sure the name in  is the some in jndi-name